# Zoom and pan on a SVG map

Tags: reactjs, svg

I have a SVG map as one of my react components, and I am trying to make it so you can zoom in on the map, and pan across so certain sections are easier to see. I have managed to implement being able to zoom in on the map, however the map just enlarges on the screen rather than zooming within the view box I have, and the zoom is quite sensitive and the map will often disappear if it zooms out too far. Does anyone have experience who can help with this. The code for the zoom came from someone who was using it to zoom in on images. `

Here is the code minus all the path data for the SVG as it was too many characters

```js
import React, {useState, useRef, useEffect}  from 'react'




export default function Map () {

    const [pos, setPos] = useState({ x: 0, y: 0, scale: 1 });

    const onScroll = (e) => {
      const delta = e.deltaY * -0.01;
      const newScale = pos.scale + delta;
  
      const ratio = 1 - newScale / pos.scale;
  
      setPos({
        scale: newScale,
        x: pos.x + (e.clientX - pos.x) * ratio,
        y: pos.y + (e.clientY - pos.y) * ratio
      });
    }; 

   
    return (
        <>
        
        
        
        <div className='viewBox'>
        <div onWheelCapture={onScroll}>
        <svg baseProfile="tiny" fill="#7c7c7c" height="1982" stroke="#ffffff" strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" strokeWidth="2" version="1.2" viewBox="0 0 1000 1982" width="1000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  style={{transformOrigin: '0 0', transform: `translate(${pos.x}px, ${pos.y}px) scale(${pos.scale})`}}>
```

Comment: And you read all the other answers? https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsvg%5D+zoom+pan

Comment: Hey, if that is the node module pan zoom thing, I was able to use that, however I wasn't able to change the background color and stuff so the look was not what I was going for so I wanted to try and do it on my own